# The dimensions are 1285, the selected element is the same as well. Why is there a horizontal scroll there?

Tags: html, css

[The horizontal scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWoFB.png), I didn't intend it to be there, I am new to web design and have no clue how to proceed. This isn't my primary domain, was trying to make a site for my purpose. What should I do?

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

is in my code.

This white space also shows up on my iPad and iPhone when hosted and I attempt to scroll horizontally, but on my Mac, there is no scroll present(unless I do what I did in the image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that your header is creating an overflow in the x axis, this may be because there is an implicit style in the body or header tag. Try editing your css with one or two of the following suggestions:

1. Set styles for your body tag (* is also an option):

> ```
> body {
>   margin: 0;
>   padding: 0;
> }
> ```

2. Set the width of your header to fill app space:

> ```
> header {
>   width: 100%;
> }
> ```

Please let me know if this helps you. Best regards!

Comment: I don't know which element is causing the overflow; I checked all elements on my page and all fit within the viewport. The only item which is larger than the viewport is the [fixed navigation bar](https://imgur.com/a/i0ypXSI) ONLY when scrolled. But on editing the width(to 1404px or 100% in the above image) in chrome, still, the white space remains.

Comment: Addition: I found the issue. It was a rookie mistake(that I am) I made, by adding a margin on all sides which I didn't realize since it had my socials. Thank you for your help kind sir!